# How to display the Kinect point cloud using image colours?

Tags: kinect, rviz, openni, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How can I display the point cloud created by the Kinect in colours obtained from the camera, rather than in artificial colours related to depth?  Both /camera/rgb/points and /camera/depth/points topics display using the artificial colouring.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9320/how-to-display-the-kinect-point-cloud-using-image-colours?/) by [JediHamster](https://answers.ros.org/users/146/jedihamster/) on ROS Answers with karma: 995 on 2011-03-07

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Jedi Hamster,

I believe you want the RGB8 setting in the Color Transformer pulldown in RViz under your Point Cloud display.  This option appears only when you are using /camera/rgb/points rather than /camera/depth/points.

--patrick

P.S. May the Force be with you.

---

Originally posted by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) with karma: 4046 on 2011-03-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 8

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JediHamster](https://answers.ros.org/users/146/jedihamster/) on 2011-03-07**:
Aha!  Nice.

**Comment by [harsha](https://answers.ros.org/users/3217/harsha/) on 2012-09-21**:
In the PointCloud2 display we can use the topic */camera/depth_registered/points* and select RGB8 from the Color Transformer pulldown options.